# POST data becomes NULL after form submit (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have a problem on getting post data after submitting a form. What I'm trying to do is that, when the user clicks the submit button, input values stored in the hidden fields will be assigned to a variable into another controller class. However, when I tried to print out the form value, its always giving me `NULL`

This is my code:

Controller

```
public function updateOrder(){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('delivery_status_id', 'Delivery Status', 'xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('remarks', 'Remarks', 'xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('total_amt', 'Total Amount', 'xss_clean');

    $data = array('remarks' => $this->input->post('remarks'),
                  'delivery_status_id' => $this->input->post('delivery_status_id'),
                  'total_amt' => $this->input->post('total_amt'));

    if ($data['delivery_status_id'] == $getDeliveryStatusIdDelivered->row('id'))
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user_has_penalty');
        $this->db->where("user_id =" . $this->session->userdata['id']);

        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
        {
            $this->db->delete('user_has_penalty', array('user_id' => $this->session->userdata['id']));
            $this->db->delete('penalty', array('id' => $row->penalty_id));
        }
    }else if($data['delivery_status_id'] == $getDeliveryStatusIdCancelled->row('id'))
    {
        $penalty_amt = $data['total_amt'] / 2;
        $data = array('amount' => $penalty_amt);
        $this->penalty->insert($data);
        $penalty_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        //var_dump($penalty_id);
    }

    var_dump($this->input->post); // Outputs NULL
}
```

View

```
...

<?php
    $name_c = 'Cancelled';
    $query = $this->DeliveryStatus->getDeliveryStatusByName($name_c);

    echo form_open('Order_Controller/updateOrder');
?>
    <input type="hidden" name="delivery_status_id" value="<?php echo $query->row('id'); ?>"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">YES</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Is there something wrong with the code? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: First thing to check is the HTML Code being generated. Are you seeing what values are being generated in your hidden field?

Comment: `Print_r($_POST)` and check what you posted

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I've already tried to inspect the element, and yes, I'm getting the values I expected

Comment: It appears you have set your post values into $data... so you could perform a var_dump on that... Also you could var_dump($this->input->post()) [ and No you haven't] and you are setting rules on the inputs but not performing a validation test - see https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html?highlight=form

Answer (score 2):

In your form tag, if you do not specify the method it will be `get` method.

```
<form action="Order_Controller/updateOrder" method="post">

...

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `method` in your form tag.

```
 form_open('order_Controller/updateOrder', array('method'=>'post'));
```

Note:

1. Please use model for database related queries.
2. Pass the query result to the controller and then to the view.
3. You can add your validation in configuration. To handle all validation at one place.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This Will outputs always null 
var_dump($this->input->post);
// To Get Value Array from codeigniter input class 

var_dump($this->input->post());
method will return the values in $_POST variable 

because you are accessing uninitialized property of a object
The correct way to get post variable from codeigniter input class is 

$this->input->post() is equivalent to $_POST;
$this->input->post('data') is equivalent to $_POST['data']
```